# how can i access my system resources without the operating system intermediation?

Tags: windows, linux, unix, operating-system, native-code

i want to access my system resources such as CPU without the use of OS system calls.
is there any way to make this possible?

Comment: What does "*accessing your system resources*" mean to you? You cannot start any user application without system calls... (at the very least, `execve` of its binary executable).

Comment: i don't want a complete independent program, i can't ignore system calls for a usual program that is running on a OS. my question is that can i access and manage my program's or other program's resources in special situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to access the hardware directly on most modern operating systems, Linux and Windows included, is via kernel code. [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) is an excellent starting point for writing such code on Linux, even if it is a bit dated.

Otherwise, the OS provides various I/O facilities and controls the allocation of resources to the user applications, using the system call interface. The system call interface is omnipresent in its basic concept among all operating systems that actually have some sort of separation between kernel and user code. The use of software interrupts is the standard way to implement system calls on current hardware.

You need a system call to allocate the slightest amount of memory and even to read or write a single character. Not to mention that even a program that does *absolutely nothing* generally needs a few system calls just to be loaded.

You could gain more direct access to the hardware if you used [DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) or an [exokernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exokernel) design.

But *why* would you want to do that anyway? Modern hardware is far from trivial to work with directly.

Comment: because of a bet! what about thread management in my own CPU timeslot?

Comment: Well, you can certainly create your own notion of a thread in your own timeslot without using the OS MT system, but it would not be quite as functional. You could not, for example, be able to run a thread in a different CPU core - not without an actual OS thread.

Comment: @sia: you might find [the GNU Portable Threads library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Portable_Threads) interesting...

Comment: I believe that you lost your bet. The role of the kernel is to abstract & manage the raw CPU and hardware

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch: i don't, i have a chance of managing and accessing my own resources that has been already allocated to my program by the OS.

Comment: @sia: well, you can certainly manage any resource that has already been allocated, but don't expect it to be easy. The Java VM has that down to an art, having its own memory and thread management facilities.

Comment: "GNU Pth uses a M:1 mapping to kernel-space threads". not working for me!

Comment: @sia: Why not? You need *at least* one kernel thread, or you wouldn't have a running program...

Comment: @thkala: thanks java VM is a good choice, do you have any direct reference?

Comment: @sia: Well, the memory management is evident, since Java uses a garbage collector. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads#Green_threads_in_the_Java_virtual_machine) and [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/threads/threads.html) for some historical JVM threading information.

Comment: @thkala: thanx alot, by the way python thread manager has the same methods i think, any way thank u;

Comment: I still believe that you are losing your bet, because what you can manage inside a Linux process is only the *abstracted resources* provided by the Linux "virtual machine" defined by the kernel interfaces (ie the 250+ system calls). You are not managing the raw resources (the real processor, for instance), only what the kernel is showing you.